# Getting "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." in custom control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have created Custom Entry control in Xamarin cross platform. But don't know why exception is coming. Where am i doing wrong?

Here's my code

CustomEntry.cs

```
public class CustomEntry : Entry
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty cornerRadiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Radius",typeof(double),typeof(CustomEntry),0);
        public double CornerRadius { 
            get { return (double)GetValue(cornerRadiusProperty);}
            set { SetValue(cornerRadiusProperty, value);  }
        }
    }
```

MyXaml Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:cl="clr-namespace:customcontrolapp;assembly=customcontrolapp" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="customcontrolapp.MyXaml" >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <cl:CustomEntry Text="Sample" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: There must be a Exception underneath this. Closely inspect your Output window.

Comment: You're putting an int as the default value which it can't handle being a double. Try 0.0 as a default. Also, the propertyName parameter is set as `Radius` whereas your property is called `CornerRadius`. For this to work they should match. You could also use `nameof(CornerRadius)` to reduce your magic string usage :)

Comment: @StevenThewissen Thanks..your suggestion worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this exception changes linker option link all to SDK Linking only. 
Thanks